# googletesting out of range

Tags: c++, exception, googletest

I have a `vector<string>` and a method(inside a class) that returns a character at a certain position.
This is all happening in try catch block.

The problem appears when I try to google test this method, purposely invoking the `std::out_of_range` exception with `EXPECT_THROW(method, std::out_of_range)`, but  instead of getting a passed test I get several `.what()` error messages `vector::_M_range_check` and a test failure.

mentioned method

```
char ClassA::getC(int x, int y){
    try{
         return vec.at(y).at(x);

    catch(const out_of_range& e){
         cout << '\n' << e.what() << '\n';
         return 0;
    }
}
```

There's also a similar `void` method that sets a different char at a certain position where I just call `vec.at(y).at(x) = c;` and where I'd also like to catch `std::out_of_range`

So what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`EXPECT_THROW(method, std::out_of_range)`

What you're saying here is that you expect the method to throw this exception. That's what is wrong.

That'll never happen because that exception is handled in the method.

The error messages come from `cout << ...`.

On a more fundamental level, your tested function is wrong. That's not the way you want to handle exceptions in your application.

Comment: so should I delete the try catch?

Comment: probably... and if the app relied on it, you'll have some more work to do.

Comment: do you have any hints :P